# failed to git pull same file from specific commit id in local machine?

Tags: git, git-pull

## Env：

- macOS 10.13.5

## Git init and push changed files in local machine

Notes：XXX is username of local machine

```
    ➜  gittest git init
    Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/XXX/Desktop/gittest/.git/
    ➜  gittest git:(master) echo "hello" > 1.md
    ➜  gittest git:(master) ✗ git add 1.md
    ➜  gittest git:(master) ✗ git commit -m"hello"
[master (root-commit) ea37549] hello
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 1.md
    gittest git:(master) ✗ git push --set-upstream /Users/XXX/Desktop/gittest/.git/ master
    Branch 'master' set up to track remote branch 'master' from '/Users/XXX/Desktop/gittest/.git/'.
    Everything up-to-date
    gittest git:(master) ✗ echo "hello 2" >>1.md # change files
    ➜  gittest git:(master) ✗ git add 1.md
    ➜  gittest git:(master) ✗ git commit -m"hello 2"
[master 4593958] hello2
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
    ➜  gittest git:(master) ✗ git push
    Everything up-to-date
```

## Git Pull the first commit files but failed

```
➜  gittest git:(master) git pull
From /Users/XXX/Desktop/gittest/
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up to date.
```

But it could not return file that was first commited to git push.

## Expected

- Git pull files with specified commit id and cover origin files with same names.
- I don't want to use remote server or repository(e.g. Github).Please don't give solutions about it.
- I don't want to create another branch and merge it. I just want to finish my goal in a master branch.

Comment: Are you trying to pull a single commit?

Answer (score 1):

**You have got a lot of things mixed up**

`git init` creates a full repository, therefore `git commit` is the command to create a revision in that repository.

`git push` is used to send changes to **other** repositories. You actually just created a self-reference to the same repository with your push. Therefore, everything is up-to-date, because you are trying to update the repository itself.

`git pull` is used to get changes from **other** repositories and is by default a shortcut for `git fetch` (update the local knowledge about remote repository) and `git merge` to merge try to merge a current branch with the updated local knowledge of the branch in remote repository.

If you do not want to deal with remote repositories, do not use `git pull` and `git push`.

**Moving around Git**

To move to a specific commit in the repository, use `git checkout`. But beware, `git checkout <commit id>` will end up in **detached HEAD** state.